.NET MAUI TabbedPage customization for required style themes
MY EXPECTATION
I want to change the colors of the tabbed page themes as per my need.
Default tabbed page theme

Tabbed page theme I want

Environment .NET MAUI, C#, .NET 8
WHAT I HAVE TRIED
I tried adding below two configurations in TabbedPage
BarBackgroundColor = UIHelper.DarkBackgroundColor;
BarTextColor = Colors.White;

which gave below result. But here there is NO difference in between selected tab and unselected tab.
I want clear difference between selected vs unselected tabs. please suggest


I am able to fix this by using below two changes
C# code in TabbedPage related class
BarBackgroundColor = UIHelper.DarkBackgroundColor;
UnselectedTabColor = Color.FromRgb(208, 208, 208);
SelectedTabColor = UIHelper.SecondaryAppColor;

Styles.xml file changes
<style name="Maui.MainTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="tabStyle">@style/CustomTabTabStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- Custom Tab style -->
<style name="CustomTabTabStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">#ED7E03</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorAnimationMode">elastic</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorAnimationDuration">300</item>
    <item name="android:transition">@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
</style>


As requested to change theme by code only:

Create SharedClass


Enum_TabbedPage_Theme | TabbedPageTheme_1 | TabbedPageTheme_2 | Update_TabbedPageTheme


Usage for testing (From Code-Behind of TabbedPage)

SharedClass.Update_TabbedPageTheme(this, SharedClass.Enum_TabbedPage_Theme.TabbedPageTheme_1);


Or
SharedClass.Update_TabbedPageTheme(this, SharedClass.Enum_TabbedPage_Theme.TabbedPageTheme_2);


public static class SharedClass
{
    public enum Enum_TabbedPage_Theme
    {
        TabbedPageTheme_1, TabbedPageTheme_2
    }
    //------------------------------------------------
    public static TabbedPage_Theme TabbedPageTheme_1 =
       new TabbedPage_Theme()
       {
           BarBackgroundColor = Colors.Blue,
           UnselectedTabColor = Colors.Green,
           SelectedTabColor = Colors.Red
       };
    //------------------------------------------------
    public static TabbedPage_Theme TabbedPageTheme_2 =
       new TabbedPage_Theme()
       {
           BarBackgroundColor = Colors.Orange,
           UnselectedTabColor = Colors.Blue,
           SelectedTabColor = Colors.Fuchsia
       };
    //------------------------------------------------
    public static void Update_TabbedPageTheme(TabbedPage Source_TabbedPage, Enum_TabbedPage_Theme Selected_Theme)
    {
        switch (Selected_Theme)
        {
            case Enum_TabbedPage_Theme.TabbedPageTheme_1:
                Source_TabbedPage.BarBackgroundColor = TabbedPageTheme_1.BarBackgroundColor;
                Source_TabbedPage.UnselectedTabColor = TabbedPageTheme_1.UnselectedTabColor;
                Source_TabbedPage.SelectedTabColor = TabbedPageTheme_1.SelectedTabColor;
                break;
            case Enum_TabbedPage_Theme.TabbedPageTheme_2:
                Source_TabbedPage.BarBackgroundColor = TabbedPageTheme_2.BarBackgroundColor;
                Source_TabbedPage.UnselectedTabColor = TabbedPageTheme_2.UnselectedTabColor;
                Source_TabbedPage.SelectedTabColor = TabbedPageTheme_2.SelectedTabColor;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}


public class TabbedPage_Theme
{
    public Color BarBackgroundColor { get; set; } = Colors.White;
    public Color UnselectedTabColor { get; set; } = Colors.Grey;
    public Color SelectedTabColor { get; set; } = Colors.Yellow;
}


For General theme changing | Follow this structure
It will guide you how to access and use colors in .Xaml file, it is accessible in all platforms.

Define default colors:
Main_1_Color | Main_2_Color | Main_3_Color
Colors 1:
ThemeDark_Main_1_Color | ThemeDark_Main_2_Color | ThemeDark_Main_3_Color
Colors 2:
ThemeLight_Main_1_Color | ThemeLight_Main_2_Color | ThemeLight_Main_3_Color
*** NOTE: YOU CAN ADD MORE [Follow Default & Color 1,2 ] ***
Colors 3 : ThemeXXX_Main_1_Color | ThemeXXX_Main_2_Color | ThemeXXX_Main_3_Color | ThemeXXX_Main_4_Color ...


Usage:
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource Main_1_Color}" />
</Style>

OR

 <Border StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 20" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Main_3_Color}">


To change the theme you can call the static function with the prefix name as a parameter
UpdateThemeColor("ThemeLight");
UpdateThemeColor("ThemeDark");



[ProjectName]\Resources\Styles\Colors.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xaml-comp compile="true" ?>
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

<Color x:Key="Main_1_Color">#2b2b44</Color>
<Color x:Key="Main_2_Color">#343453</Color>
<Color x:Key="Main_3_Color">#42426a</Color>

<Color x:Key="ThemeDark_Main_1_Color">#2b2b44</Color>
<Color x:Key="ThemeDark_Main_2_Color">#343453</Color>
<Color x:Key="ThemeDark_Main_3_Color">#42426a</Color>

<Color x:Key="ThemeLight_Main_1_Color">#bdb1ae</Color>
<Color x:Key="ThemeLight_Main_2_Color">#F8E1D4</Color>
<Color x:Key="ThemeLight_Main_3_Color">#d2d3db</Color>

</ResourceDictionary>

Static class.cs
#region Themes
public static void UpdateThemeColor(string themeName)
{
    ICollection<ResourceDictionary> mergedDictionaries = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries;

    if (mergedDictionaries is not null)
    {
        foreach (ResourceDictionary dictionaries in mergedDictionaries)
        {
            var Main_1_Color = dictionaries.TryGetValue(themeName + "_" + "Main_1_Color", out var out_Main_1_Color);
            if (Main_1_Color)
            {
                dictionaries["Main_1_Color"] = out_Main_1_Color;
            }

            var Main_2_Color = dictionaries.TryGetValue(themeName + "_" + "Main_2_Color", out var out_Main_2_Color);
            if (Main_2_Color)
            {
                dictionaries["Main_2_Color"] = out_Main_2_Color;
            }

            var Main_3_Color = dictionaries.TryGetValue(themeName + "_" + "Main_3_Color", out var out_Main_3_Color);
            if (Main_3_Color)
            {
                dictionaries["Main_3_Color"] = out_Main_3_Color;
            }
        }

        Preferences.Default.Set("themeName", themeName);
    }
}
#endregion


Thank you for your answer. But I'm new to XAML and as per our current approach we are not using XAML. So can you please help to achieve this in C#.

@Chandramouli, Welcome, kindly check the updates

Thank you. Your answer is close to my requirement. But when we apply the BarBackgroundColor = Colors.Blue then i need a white line at the bottom of the selected tab. just like second image in your answer has blue line at the bottom of the selected tab. Can you please help with this so that i will mark it as answer.

why in one case it is DynamicResource and in the other case it is StaticResource ?

@pf12345678910, Just an example for different USAGE and not all controls supportting DynamicResource it should be StaticResource and requires restarting the APP when you config/load Preferences.Default.Set("themeName", themeName)

for me it is not working, the UI does not move an inch, the dictionary gets updated, but that's all that happens. also in the for loop looking for merged dictionaries, the color never gets found

@pf12345678910, this code for MAUI not WPF are you taking about MAUI ?

@Chandramouli, i need a white line at the bottom of the selected tab I've been working on this for long time with no success, it requires Custom handlers for each platform, meainwhile you can search about that, till someone else post an answer or I could find the solution, update your question with that point please

Thank you so @MustafaMutasim for spending time to find the approach for my problem. Please let me know if you have any solution. and I will also update if I found any solution for this.

*I want clear difference between selected vs unselected tabs. * The quickest and easiest way is to set SelectedTabColor and UnselectedTabColor.

@JianweiSun-MSFT, set BarBackgroundColor = Colors.Orange,UnselectedTabColor = Colors.Blue,SelectedTabColor = Colors.Fuchsia

@JianweiSun-MSFT, I want clear difference to modify the default style , you must create Custom handlers/Custom Renderer its too complicated to implement, it's about working with native UI Android/iOS/Windows

Yes, indeed. For Android, I tried to modify it by handler, but the platformview is ViewPager2...

@MustafaMutasim Is there a way to increase the height of the tab indicator?


.NET MAUI TabbedPage customization for required style themes

You can modify it by using platform native code. Add the following code in your TabbedPage code behind:
    protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
    {
        base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if ANDROID
        FieldInfo tabbedPageManagerFieldInfo = typeof(TabbedPage).GetField("_tabbedPageManager", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        object tabbedPageManager = tabbedPageManagerFieldInfo?.GetValue(this);
        FieldInfo tabLayoutFieldInfo = tabbedPageManager?.GetType().GetField("_tabLayout", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var tablayout = tabLayoutFieldInfo?.GetValue(tabbedPageManager) as Google.Android.Material.Tabs.TabLayout;
        if (tablayout != null)
        {
            tablayout.SetSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#000000"));
        }
#endif
    }

Use Reflection to get TabbedPageManager(cause it is internal class) and TabLayout. Then call SetSelectedTabIndicatorColor method to set Indicator Color. I set it to black color.
